# Copy text box content to another textbox while typing for every click char click using jQuery

Tags: jquery

Need to display textbox1 content to textbox2 for every keypress and need to trigger click automatically on second textbox for every click. I tried  below code and able to copy from textbox to another and need to call click event automatically in second textbox.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#test1').on("keypress change keyup", function(e) {
      var txtVal = $(this).val();
      $('#test2').val(txtVal);
      $("#test2").trigger('click');
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <input type="text" class="" placeholder="" id="test1" name="" />
  <input type="text" class="" placeholder="" id="test2" name="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define the click event handler for `#test2` outside of the key events for `#test1`. In addition you need to use `trigger()` to 'transfer' the click event from `#test1` to `'test2`.

Try the below example. Note the use of `input` as it covers all the events you originally bound, in addition to content added through copy+paste via the mouse-controlled context boxes.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  let $test1 = $('#test1');
  let $test2 =$('#test2'); 
  
  $test1.on({
    input: e => $test2.val(e.target.value),
    click: e => $test2.trigger('click')
  });
  
  $test2.on('click', e => console.log('Click event caught by test2'));  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="" placeholder="" id="test1" name="" />
<input type="text" class="" placeholder="" id="test2" name="" />
```